# How to make lightning-layout-item grow horizontally or vertically or both?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-design-system, slds, web-components

I'm trying to create a flexible layout using lightning-layout and lightning-layout-item base components in LWC. The screenshot of the basic idea is given below. Appreciate inputs on how can we achieve such a layout either using lightning base components, SLDS, or generic CSS.

[image]